# Parse nested JSON code in IOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to parse the following JSON code in iOS. The JSON code consists of an array of games numbered 0 to x. I've been searching around but cant seem to find any examples which have JSON in this format.

```
{
"command":"show_my_games",
"0":{"gameid":"7","foruserid":"16","againstuserid":"0","casefor":"","caseagainst":"","status":"0","argumentid":"7","againstusername":null,"forusername":"Gem","argument":"argument 1"},
"1":{"gameid":"8","foruserid":"15","againstuserid":"16","casefor":"","caseagainst":"","status":"0","argumentid":"23","againstusername":"Gem","forusername":"Nick","argument":"argument 2"},
"2":{"gameid":"9","foruserid":"18","againstuserid":"16","casefor":"","caseagainst":"","status":"0","argumentid":"26","againstusername":"Gem","forusername":"Nick","argument":"argument 3"}
}
```

I've created a game object, and for each item in the JSON array, I want to create a new game object, and add this to the game array. I'm having trouble parsing the JSON, and i'd appreciate any help or advice.

The code i'm trying to use is

```
            NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];

            for (NSMutableDictionary * gameItem in json) {
                Game *obj = [Game new];
                obj.GameID=[gameItem objectForKey:@"gameid"];
                obj.Argument=[gameItem objectForKey:@"argument"];
                obj.CaseFor=[gameItem objectForKey:@"casefor"];
                obj.CaseAgainst=[gameItem objectForKey:@"caseagainst"];
                obj.CaseForOwner=[gameItem objectForKey:@"forusername"];
                obj.CaseAgainstOwner=[gameItem objectForKey:@"againstusername"];
                obj.CaseForOwnerID=[gameItem objectForKey:@"foruserid"];
                obj.CaseAgainstOwnerID=[gameItem objectForKey:@"againstuserid"];
                //add to the players game array
                [myGameArray addObject:obj];

            }
            NSLog(@"array: %@", myGameArray);
```

When I try extracting data from the JSON array, I receive the following error.
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1f06f4e0

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: Peel the onion, one layer at a time.  Your outermost structure is a dictionary, not an array.  It's got dictionary elements named "1", "2", "3", and "command".

Comment: And the value of the "command" dictionary entry is "show_my_games", which is a string, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is breaking as the object for the key `command` is not a dictionary.

You can modify the code like this.

```
    for (NSString *key in json){
        id object = json[key];
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
           Game *obj = [Game new];
           obj.GameID=[gameItem objectForKey:@"gameid"];
           obj.Argument=[gameItem objectForKey:@"argument"];
           obj.CaseFor=[gameItem objectForKey:@"casefor"];
           obj.CaseAgainst=[gameItem objectForKey:@"caseagainst"];
           obj.CaseForOwner=[gameItem objectForKey:@"forusername"];
           obj.CaseAgainstOwner=[gameItem objectForKey:@"againstusername"];
           obj.CaseForOwnerID=[gameItem objectForKey:@"foruserid"];
           obj.CaseAgainstOwnerID=[gameItem objectForKey:@"againstuserid"];
           //add to the players game array
          [myGameArray addObject:obj];
    }
```

I would suggest to make an `initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary` in your `Game` class for more cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the type gameItem "`NSMutableDictionary`" to "`id`" and add the checking - `if ([gameItem isKindOfClass: [NSDictionary Class]])` and in the case of this condition initialize "`obj`"